# Need java double to not round down

Tags: java, math, int, double, java.util.scanner

I need java to keep the results their true values, here is my code:

`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int test1;
int test2;
int quiz1;
int quiz2;
int quiz3;
double homework;
System.out.println("Please enter your test grades.");
test1 = scan.nextInt();
test2 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter you quiz grades.");
quiz1 = scan.nextInt();
quiz2 = scan.nextInt();
quiz3 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter your homework average.");
homework = scan.nextDouble();
double quizaverage = (quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3)/3;
double testaverage = (test1 + test2)/2;
System.out.println("Test Average " + (testaverage) + "");
System.out.println("quiz Average " + (quizaverage) + "");
double finalgrade = (testaverage) * 0.5 + (quizaverage)* 0.3 + (homework) * 0.2;
System.out.println("Final Grade " + (finalgrade) + "");`
```

The values I am inputting:
 `*test 1=89, test 2=86, quiz 1=84, quiz 2=84, quiz 3=83, homework=90.12*`

Everything works but the problem is I need the *test average* variable and *quiz average* variable to not round down, because I am getting **87.0 for my test average** and **83.0 for my quiz average** when I run the program, those values then affect the final grade variable because I need to get 86.874 for the final grade, not 86.424. so I their true values of **87.5 for the test average** and **83.66666666666667 for the quiz average** to get the true final grade. Basically I need to know how to prevent java from rounding down (I think). I hope I did not make it sound complicated, all help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wrong division in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553047/wrong-division-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing integer division, which in Java results in another `int`.  You need to force floating-point division with your math; assigning to a `double` doesn't force it.  Use a floating-point literal, with `.0` on the end.

```
double quizaverage = (quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3)/3.0;
double testaverage = (test1 + test2)/2.0;
```

(Casting either operand to a `double` would work also.)

Comment: I also found that using casts and making it ``((double)quiz1 + (double)quiz2 + (double)quiz3)/3;`` also worked.